edit text box contents word
I inserted it into a word document un textbox (activex control) I would like to access this control for example by modifying the content of the text I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms;
 

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application alex = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document alexdoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
            alexdoc = null;
            try
            {
               
                alexdoc = alex.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\Alex\Documents\doc1.docx");
                alex.Visible = false;
                
                
                foreach (Shape shape in alexdoc.Shapes)
                {
                    if (shape.OLEFormat != null && shape.OLEFormat is Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.TextBox)
                    {
                        var nome = (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.TextBox)shape.OLEFormat.Object;
                        nome.Text = "alex";
                        var TextBox1 = (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.TextBox)shape.OLEFormat.Object;
                        TextBox1.Text = "riuscito";

                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(shape.Name);

                }

                alexdoc.SaveAs2(@"C:\Users\Alex\Documents\alexmodificato.docx");
                
            }

            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                label1.Text = "errore" + ex.Message;

            }
            finally
            {
                alexdoc?.Close(false);
                alex.Quit();
                alexdoc = null;
                alex = null;
            }
        }
    }
}


I hope you can help me with the code or tell me where to find the documentation
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms;
 

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application alex = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document alexdoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
            alexdoc = null;
            try
            {
               
                alexdoc = alex.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\Alex\Documents\doc1.docx");
                alex.Visible = false;
                
                
                foreach (Shape shape in alexdoc.Shapes)
                {
                    if (shape.OLEFormat != null && shape.OLEFormat is Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.TextBox)
                    {
                        var nome = (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.TextBox)shape.OLEFormat.Object;
                        nome.Text = "alex";
                        var TextBox1 = (Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.TextBox)shape.OLEFormat.Object;
                        TextBox1.Text = "riuscito";

                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(shape.Name);

                }

                alexdoc.SaveAs2(@"C:\Users\Alex\Documents\alexmodificato.docx");
                
            }

            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                label1.Text = "errore" + ex.Message;

            }
            finally
            {
                alexdoc?.Close(false);
                alex.Quit();
                alexdoc = null;
                alex = null;
            }
        }
    }
}



tell me where to find the documentation: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Namespace

I see you are just starting coding. No problem! Been there.
The office documents are packed with different kinds of xml-files. If you select a docx-file and open it with winrar or winzip, you'll see it. There are also a lot of libraries you can use in the NuGet Package manager (Right side in vs -> right click our solution -> Manage NuGet Packages) and search for docx.
